# Text cursor positioning is not happening properly in IE >= 10 and Firefox 37

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer, firefox

Mouse cursor position is not happening properly when user performs the click operation on editable div + whose parent is having draggable property with true value.

**Some thing like below:**

```
<div class="a" draggable="true"> 
    <div contenteditable="true" class="b"> Edit Me </div>
</div>
```

Ref: http://jsfiddle.net/oksywpc4/4/

Note: This scenario is working well in chrome but not in IE >=10

Comment: Can anybody suggest a solution or workaround, waiting badly.